# Range and kernel of linear transformations over vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\Range}{\operatorname{Range}}$

> Consider non-zero vector spaces $V_1, V_2, V_3, V_4$ and linear transformations $\phi_1: V_1 \to V_2$, $\phi_2: V_2 \to V_3$, $\phi_3 V_3 \to V_4$ such that $\ker \phi_1 = \{0\}$, $\Range \phi_1 = \ker \phi_2$, $\Range \phi_2 = \ker \phi_3$, and $\Range \phi_3 = V_4$.  Then, is it the case that:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^4 (-1)^i\dim V_i = 0 \tag{1}$$
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^4 (-1)^i\dim V_i > 0 \tag{2}$$
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^4 (-1)^i\dim V_i < 0 \tag{3}$$
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^4 (-1)^i\dim V_i \neq 0 \tag{4}$$

I cannot  think  of  any  theorem or  general  results regarding  this. So I tried  with  random  examples and  each  time  got  option $1$. But  the  answer  sheet  says  option $2$  is  also true  and $3,4$  are  wrong. I  also  observed  one  space's  dimension could  restrict  the  possibilities of  other  dimensions . But  no  general  results  yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d_1,...,d_4$ be the dimensions of $V_1,...,V_4.$  Since we're given that $\phi_1$ has trivial kernel, it must be injective.  Hence the dimension of $\phi_1$'s image must be $d_1.$  In general, we have a relation between the dimensions of the image and kernel of a linear operator - they add to the dimension of the domain.  We can use this fact to compute the dimensions of the kernels and images of the other operators.

We know that the dimension of $\phi_2$'s image is $d_1$, so its kernel has dimension $d_2-d_1.$  Similarly we see that $\phi_3$ has an image of dimension $d_3-(d_2-d_1)=d_3-d_2+d_1.$ From the problem, this is also the dimension of $V_4.$

This should be enough information to finish out the problem.